# Accessing elements of the std::string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c-strings

How to access the below array elements and print the elements of type uint8_t in hex format in C++?

```
std::string arr[] = {"0x01","0x02","0x03","0x04","0x05","0x06"}
```

How to print each element using c_str()?

Comment: You can access them with the subscript operator, eg `arr[1]` for the second one.  But none of them are type `uint8_t`, they're all `std::string`.

Comment: is it possible using static_cast or reinterpret_cast?

Comment: What do you mean by "point each elements"? Do you mean print?

Comment: @MysteriousUser yes

Comment: It's really not clear what you want to do.  Do you want to print the strings in the array?  Or the numeric value of the characters within one of the strings?  Why do you need `c_str()` specifically?

Comment: @Dmitri yes, I wanted to print the numeric value of str::string array  elements in hex format. Any method to achieve this is fine. Not limited to c_str().

Comment: `arr[1][3]` would get you the 4th `char` in the 2nd `std::string` in the array `arr`, if that helps.

Comment: @VasudaR perhaps you meant to do `uint8_t arr[] = {0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06};`?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili no, the array is of type std::string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to parse strings, here is how you do it:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string arr[] = {"0x01", "0x02", "0x03", "0x04", "0x05", "0x06"};

  std::uint8_t arr2[6];

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i) arr2[i] = std::stoi(arr[i], nullptr, 16);

  for (auto e : arr2) std::printf("%#x\n", e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`uint8_t` is a special int type. The standard allows it to be processed the same as `unsigned char` by the formatting methods.

If you really want to convert each string to a `uint8_t`, you will have to use an `int` as an intermediary value, both for input and output:

```
std::string arr[] = { "0x01","0x02","0x03","0x04","0x05","0x06" };

for (const std::string& s : arr) {
    std::stringstream str(s);          // use a stringstream for the conversion
    int i;
    str >> std::hex >> i;
    uint8_t u = i;                     // you have the expected uint8_t
    // but you will have to cast them to int again to print them
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(u) << ' ';
}
```

---

To print an int in hexadecimal, you must `#include <iomanip>` and use `std::hex`:

```
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(u) << ' ';
```

Comment: This gives me an error like this
error: variable ‘std::stringstream str’ has initializer but incomplete type

Comment: @VasudaR you have to `#include <sstream>`

Comment: is it not possible to print as a hex value?

Answer (score 0):

As Dmitri commented, the elements of your array are of type `std::string`. They do encode unsigned integers formatted as hex. If your goal is to simply print them, this will suffice:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string arr[] = {"0x01","0x02","0x03","0x04","0x05","0x06"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If you need the values in the array to be of type `uint8_t`, you need to explicitly convert them first.

Comment: yes, I want to print the same array elements of type uint_8.